# How to correctly POST with axios to Node server with localhost in baseURL?

Tags: node.js, post, get, axios, localhost

I am running a Node server locally on port 3000. I am using axios in ReactNative app to get and post data from the server.

I am setting the baseURL as:

```
const axiosObj = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000'
});
```

This is not working and resulting in Network Error. However, if I use baseURL like this then it works

```
const axiosObj = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://172.XX.X.X:3000'
});
```

I have also tried with `baseURL:http://127.0.0.1:3000` which also doesn't work

I really need it to work with `http://localhost:3000` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000` without having to provide the actual IP address. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: check your OS `hosts` file to see if `127.0.0.1 localhost` is set.

Comment: Yes. It is listed in the hosts file.

Comment: Do you still have the issue when using other clients (like curl or postman)?

Comment: no. Works fine with both Postman and Curl

Answer (score 0):

React Native app run on other device, so you can't access localhost or http:127.0.0.1 directly, use

```
adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000
```

for react-native app that run on android.
for ios, there is no way to do port reverse.

Comment: It is for ios :(